# How to implement azure B2C Sign_In policy in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I Follow this microsoft link.also sample code is there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview

and change config 
  clientId: //This is your client/application ID
 authority: "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi", //This is your tenant info
         validateAuthority: false

But It redirect to microsoft login page.
and not to login policy page which i create.
How I imaplement this in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

There are two values you should change in the config: **clinetId** and **authority**.

This is a sample of mine for your reference:

```
clientId: "7c4418ea-0e40-41a7-b5af-1aecc10fde49",
authority: "https://tonyb2ctest.b2clogin.com/tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_tonysiu",
```

[image]